# Joint Controller Plugin for Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I'm looking for a Gazebo 1.3 plugin that will allow me to send joint commands to my simulated robot arm described in SDF format. Does something like this already exist? The closest thing I've found for Gazebo 1.3 is the "gazebo pid joints" tutorial, but it is a very limited demo and I would need to put in a lot of work to make it into a fully ROS-ready controller for multiple joints. [This Controller](http://www.ros.org/wiki/actuator_array_gazebo_plugin) would be ideal except it has not been ported to the new SDF format and Gazebo version. Its source code is [here](http://code.google.com/p/gt-ros-pkg/source/browse/actuator_array/actuator_array_gazebo_plugin/?repo=humans&r=754ed2d2bb510a5ef1868db30a7c61685c1db0db). This must have already been done though, so I don't want to re-invent the wheel.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/819/joint-controller-plugin-for-gazebo/) by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 369 on 2013-01-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I've made a [ros_control_gazebo](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/ROS_Control_with_Gazebo) plugin to fix this problem.

---

Originally posted by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) with karma: 369 on 2013-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am using default pr2 controller used in '/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/pr2_simulator/pr2_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_controller_manager.cpp'.

Since we are using different version of Gazebo, so I carefully ported it into my ros-enabled plugin.

So, my pr2 in Gazebo1.3 is controlled by ROS fuerte.

---

Originally posted by [Daehyung Park](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/114/daehyung-park/) with karma: 47 on 2013-01-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dbworth](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/144/dbworth/) on 2013-01-17**:
Awesome, would you like to share this work?

**Comment by [Daehyung Park](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/114/daehyung-park/) on 2013-01-30**:
I will share it soon. Please wait.